# Solving a multi-attendee assignment problem with OR-tools

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I'm trying to solve an assignment problem similar to https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/assignment_groups using OR-tools in Python (new to OR tools). Namely, I want to assign meetings to 4 timeslots, for 3 attendees. I am given that Attendee 1 should attend M1,M2,M3, Attendee 2 should attend M2,M3, M5 and attendee 3 should attend M3, M4, M5. The other constraints are that no timeslot has more than one meeting (for each attendee) and that each meeting is assigned to exactly one timeslot (for each attendee). For simplicity I'm assuming that each attendee has 4 free timeslots.

```
!pip install ortools
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model # CP-SAT solver (primary constraint solver of ORtools)
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
num_meetings = 5
num_slots = 4



#attendees X meetings
my_array = [[1,1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1,1]]

#meetings X attendees
my_array_2 = [[0], [0,1], [1,2], [2], [0,1,2]]

# Declare the variables.
a = []
for i in range(3):
  b = []
  for j in range(num_meetings):
    c = []
    for k in range(num_slots):
      c.append(model.NewIntVar(0, 1, "a[%i,%i,%i]" % (i, j, k)))
    b.append(c)
  a.append(b)
a_array = [a[i][j][k] for i in range(3) for j in range(num_meetings) for k in range(num_slots)]


#Define the attendees of each meeting:
for d in range(3):
    for s in range(num_meetings):
        model.Add(sum(a[d][s][k] for k in range(num_slots)) == my_array[d][s])

#Requirement 1: no timeslot has more than one meeting mapped to it,
for d in range(3):
    for k in range(num_slots):
        model.Add(sum(a[d][s][k] for s in range(num_meetings)) <= 1)

#Requirement 2:
#this should force the attendees with the same meetings to have the same time slot
for i in range(num_meetings):
  print('meeting',i+1)
  print('------------')
  for j in range(len(my_array_2[i])):
    print('attendee',my_array_2[i][j]+1)
    model.Add(sum(a[my_array_2[i][j]][i][k] for k in range(num_slots)) == 1)
  print('------------')



#call the solver:
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
  print('Solved')
else:
  print(status)


#print the solutions
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(num_meetings):
    for k in range(num_slots):
      if solver.Value(a[i][j][k]) == 1:
        print('user',i+1,'meeting',j+1,'slot',k+1, 'value:',solver.Value(a[i][j][k]))
```

The solver works up to a certain point, as it assigns each meeting correctly, with no attendee having more than one meeting in the same time slot. However, for some reason, the solution forces all the meetings in the first 3 timeslots, causing the last timeslot to be free for each attendee. This causes attendees to attend the same meeting but each is in a different timeslot. Ideally, requirement 2, would force the attendees of the same meeting to meet in the same timeslot.

Comment: You have 5 meetings and only 4 slots... Remove the constraint that a slot can only hold <=1 meetings

Comment: And if `meet` is 1D array it can only model 1 attendee

Comment: Thanks @Stradivari, I would still want that constraint to hold for each individual attendee however. (each of them only needs to attend 3 out of 5 meetings so it is feasible). How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. if the problem is infeasible because of capacity, no extra constraint will make it feasible
2. you are adding 3 incompatible AddAllowedAssignment() constraints to the same list of variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The capacity problem would be addressed if each attendee was correctly mapped to their 3 corresponding meetings (I tried doing this in AddAllowedAssignment()). How could I define this problem better?